# Flying from Germany to Chicago with a 4hr layover in Dublin - Will I need a transit visa

Tags: transit, transit-visas, ireland, dub

I'm Filipino on an F1 Student Visa from the US. I'm flying back to the US from Germany. I have a 4 hour layover in Dublin on my flight back to Chicago. My flight arrives in Terminal 2 and I depart for Chicago also in Terminal 2 (Aer Lingus flight, on a single-ticket with my luggage checked through to my final destination). I know I have to go through U.S. Customs and Border Pre-Clearance. On my way to pre-clearance, will I have to go through Irish Immigration?

Answer (score 1):

As a Philippine national you do not need a transit visa for Ireland:

[image]

Soure: [INIS website](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Transit%20Visas)

You also will not go through immigration.